# Starting the dev server in project generated by vue cli 3

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, babeljs, vue-cli

I  installed vue cli 3 globally on my windows system using `npm i -g @vue/cli`.

Then  I generated a project using  `vue create vue-project`

I selected the necessary plugins needed via the prompts .

This created a vue-projject foler. Then I changed the directory into that folder and ran `npm run serve` command.

But i get the following error

```
PS E:\rk\workspace\vue-project> npm run serve

> vue-project@0.1.0 serve E:\rk\workspace\vue-project
> vue-cli-service serve

INFO  Starting development server...
94% asset optimization

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                 14:58:40

error  in ./src/main.js

Module build failed: Error: [BABEL] E:\rk\workspace\vue-project\src\main.js: The new decorators proposal is not supported yet. You must pass the `"decoratorsLegacy": true` option to @babel/preset-stage-2 (While processing: "E:\\rk\\workspace\\vue-project\\node_modules\\@vue\\babel-preset-app\\index.js$1")
    at E:\rk\workspace\vue-project\node_modules\@babel\preset-stage-2\lib\index.js:107:11
    at E:\rk\workspace\vue-project\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:18:12
    at E:\rk\workspace\vue-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:172:14
    at cachedFunction (E:\rk\workspace\vue-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:42:17)
    at loadPresetDescriptor (E:\rk\workspace\vue-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:243:63)
    at E:\rk\workspace\vue-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:68:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at recurseDescriptors (E:\rk\workspace\vue-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:66:36)
    at recurseDescriptors (E:\rk\workspace\vue-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:97:26)
    at loadFullConfig (E:\rk\workspace\vue-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:112:6)

@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client/index.js (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

How shall I rectify this?

Comment: What are the plugins that you have selected?

Comment: Happened for me with only the Unit Tests (Mocha + Chai) option with `vue create`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The fix is now available in [`v3.0.0-beta.7`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/releases/tag/v3.0.0-beta.7). It's currently an opt-in fix, so you have to add `decoratorsLegacy:true` to the `.babelrc` of a newly generated Vue project:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@vue/app",
      {
        "decoratorsLegacy": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

To fix an existing project, edit the `.babelrc` as shown above, update your `package.json` by replacing `beta.6` with `beta.7`, and re-run `yarn`/`npm install`.

<del>**TLDR:** There's a [PR (`vue-cli` #1163)](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/pull/1163) to fix the problem, but the best solution IMO is to use `.babelrc.js` (below).</del>

---

There's a GitHub [issue comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1162#issuecomment-383797149) that indicates `@babel/preset-stage-2@7.0.0-beta.44` would help, but installing it did not help. Another [suggestion](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1162#issuecomment-383796325) to replace the Babel `presets` config in `.babelrc` with the following indeed resolved the error:

```
{
  "presets": [
    // "@vue/app",  // REMOVE THIS
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": [
          "> 5%",
          "last 2 versions",
          "not ie <= 8"
        ]
      },
      "modules": false,
      "exclude": [
        "transform-regenerator"
      ]
    }],
    ["@babel/preset-stage-2", {
      "useBuiltIns": true,
      "decoratorsLegacy": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

Note the `@vue/app` preset must be removed because it [initializes `@babel/preset-stage-2`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/389ea86/packages/%40vue/babel-preset-app/index.js#L40) without the required property (`decoratorsLegacy: true`). This solution works, but it's not forward compatible with any potential improvements made in the `@vue/app` preset (including any fixes for this very problem).

### `.babelrc.js`

A more forward compatible workaround is to wrap the `@vue/app` preset and modify the config for `@babel/preset-stage-2`. When the maintainers fix `@vue/app`, we can simply revert to the default `.babelrc`. To get this working, rename `.babelrc` to `.babelrc.js`, and replace its contents with:

```js
const vueBabelPreset = require('@vue/babel-preset-app');

module.exports = (context, options = {}) => {
  // Cache the returned value forever and don't call this function again.
  context.cache(true);

  const {presets, plugins} = vueBabelPreset(context, options);

  // Find @babel/preset-stage-2, and update its config to enable `decoratorsLegacy`.
  const presetStage2 = require('@babel/preset-stage-2');
  const preset = presets.find(p => p[0] === presetStage2);
  if (preset) {
    preset[1].decoratorsLegacy = true;
  }

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant maintainers of their respective packages is aware of this problem. Per this Github [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1162#issuecomment-383708655), `vue create <project-name>` is currently broken now.

I have tried some of the solutions provided in the issue and none work for me. You could give them a try and see if they worked for you.